# width and height doesn't seem to work on :before pseudo-element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/C7rSa/) is a fiddle.

```
<p>foo <a class="infolink" href="#">bar</a> baz</p>
```

and

```
a.infolink::before
{
    content: '?';
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 20ex;
    height: 20ex;
}
```

The '?' appears but clearly does not have 20ex size. Why not? Tested in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Note: The `::before` and `::after` [pseudo-elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/#generated-content) are actually laid `display: inline;` by default.

Change the display value to `inline-block` for the width & height to take effect while maintaining inline formatting context.

```
a.infolink::before {
    content: '?';
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C7rSa/3/

Comment: Nice solution..but This does not work when the content has a base64 image string...tested on firefox 45.3

Comment: have you succeed with base64 images?

Comment: @Webwoman: Please be more specific -- if you're referring to controlling the image size through width / height then that's not the way it's supposed to work. Those attributes only control the sizing on the pseudo-element itself, not its content.

Comment: i keep forgetting that fact and always seem to come back here every now and then ;)

Answer (score 17):

`::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements are laid inline by default, so `width` and `height` won't take effect.

Set it to `display: inline-block` and [it should work](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/C7rSa/2).

Answer (score 6):

Use this if you have image in container or CSS **white-space: nowrap;** property

```
body::before{ 
    content:url(https://i.imgur.com/LJvMTyw.png);
    transform: scale(.3);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you set the **element** to `position: relative` and the **pseudo** to `position: absolute`, you can adjust the pseudo *width* and *height* in relation to the parent element size.

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    padding: 0;
}

 div::before {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked when I used `display: block`.

Answer (score 1):

add `display:block;`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C7rSa/4/)

```
p > a.infolink::before {
    display:block;
    content:'?';
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 20ex;
    height: 20ex;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can get it to work but not using a percentage in width. Pixels work fine

```
visibility: visible;
content: "stuff";
min-width: 29px;
width: 100%;
float: left;
position: relative;
top: -15px;
left: 0;
```

Comment: That's usually because you haven't set a width on the element creating the pseudo-element. Percentages aren't any different in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer the question fully, but the only solution that worked for me was using the `font-size` property.

```css
a.infolink::before
{
    content: '?';
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20ex;
}
```

```html
<p>foo <a class="infolink" href="#">bar</a> baz</p>
```