# Resizing Content Image With Browser Window?

Tags: html, css, responsive

```css
.tidings {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 3%;
  position: relative;
}

.tidings:after,
.tidings:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: opacity ease 2s;
}

.tidings:after {
 
  content: url('https://s4.postimg.org/466igrsgt/Tidingsrune.png');
}

.tidings:before {
  content: url('https://s12.postimg.org/83p4b0ubx/Tidingsrune2.png');
}

.tidings:hover:after,
.tidings:before {
  opacity: 0
}

.tidings:hover:before,
.tidings:after {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<a href="http://hvalla.deviantart.com"><span class="tidings"></span></a>
```

I am attempting to get this image link to be responsive, but I haven't had any luck so far. What would be the best method to be able to get these images to resize with the browser window?

[JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/yxusgu7L/3/)

Comment: What relation do you want? Do you want them to be centered, smaller width than the viewport, same width as the viewport, other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [width and height doesn't seem to work on :before pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858587/width-and-height-doesnt-seem-to-work-on-before-pseudo-element)

Comment: Looking for it to be smaller width than the viewport - sorry, should have specified!

Comment: @HollieOrdway `width: [Percent-Of-Viewport]%; margin: auto;`