# Insert graphics at the center of a slider with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I am trying to draw a 'center' part for a slider in css, but am running into trouble. Here's a style-less mockup of what I am aiming for: [centerslider.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUzle.png)

I tried going outside of css and manually positioning a div over the slider, but then I realized that I wanted my div to be above the slider track but below the movable cursor. I wasn't able to achieve this with z-index alone.

I also tried using the "before" and "after" events on the runnable track, so that I could add discrete content from there. And this somewhat worked once I learned that I had to use [inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858587/width-and-height-doesnt-seem-to-work-on-before-pseudo-element), but I was once more unable to get the z-index to play nicely, and it was always over the movable cursor.

In both cases, I obviously failed to achieve the overlap behavior I wanted, but it's also worth noting that I had trouble making anything behave "cleanly", where I could use the coordinate reference frame of the existing slider to place my mid-bar (something like "width:2%; left:49%" to place it).

I did see a similar functionality working in some examples, but they were overly complex for other reasons and I had trouble gleaning much from them. If someone could point me to a resource or resources or describe the bare minimum elements needed to get this working, it would help to grow my personal understanding of css. I'm not averse to learning, but I think I need to be pointed back to the right direction here at the least.

Comment: If you provide the code that you're struggling with, you're chances of getting help here will vastly improve.

Comment: please create a code snippet of your code.. we cannot help you if you don't help us by showing your code. thanks

Comment: Sorry for not providing something, but I was keeping things conceptual because there are no elements that I am concerned with other than a basic slider and some other type of element or style configuration that appears in the center of that slider (and, as I should have stated more clearly originally, is above the runnable track but below the cursor). Since I found no solution to get the latter part working and am unsure what design choice to even use to achieve this, my example code would just be a basic slider.

Answer (score 0):

is tis how you want it?? used `position:absolute` to align it

```css
.slidecontainer .fa-square {
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:50px;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 8px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 2
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="slidecontainer">
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <i class="fa fa-square"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this exhibits the main issue I was running up against - the center block overlaps both the runnable track and the movable cursor. Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I was looking for the element to appear between the two - above the track, but below the cursor. This is where I was running into problems seeing any results by playing with z-index or with this div overlay strategy in general.

Comment: Interestingly, this seems to work on Opera but I was seeing the same overlap trouble on Firefox. I haven't tried other browsers. It's possible some of the "moz-" pseudo-elements aren't defined - when I have a chance to go through the code later I will check things in more depth and tell you my findings. I think it's close though and thanks for your assistance!

Comment: I wasn't able to get the square displaying with the proper z-ordering on Firefox after some fiddling. Your solution worked on Opera and Chrome however. I suppose there must be some way to actually modify the css of the runnable track itself to display something like this that would definitely work cross-browser - but I'm not well-enough familiar to say for certain. By the way, I used this resource to determine what other "moz", etc. properties there were: http://danielstern.ca/range.css/#/

Comment: sorry forgot to add css for firefox.. yes you have to use it so the slider will look same on all the browser. thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still seeing the incorrect overlap on Firefox. What did you change in your code? Have you tested this on Firefox as well?